# How to change response body type stdObject to associative array by default in unirest for php

Tags: php, unirest

iam using unirest lib in php, so  every request have response

```
 $response = Unirest\Request::get(
                        env('JIRA_APP_DOMAIN') . 'search',
                        ['Accept' => 'application/json'],
                        [
                            'jql' => 'project = ' . env("JIRA_PROJECT_KEY") . ' AND issuetype in (' . $steps[$request->step] . ') ORDER BY priority DESC, updated DESC',
                            'maxResults' => 20,
                            'startAt' => 0
                        ]
        );
```

this $response var have body attribute, but it returns StdObject array by default

```
$response->body// gives StdObject

$response->body->name; // i dont want to use like this

$response->body['name']; // this is i want to use
```

This is heavy with slow, there is **raw_body** attribute but i dont want to convert associative array using **json_decode** function.

**There is any way to change by default body return type..**

Comment: associative array is like compare as Object.

Comment: associative array is faster and lite compare as Object

Comment: @RiggsFolly Many thanks For your support I found some code and i put this code in my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910968/how-to-change-response-body-type-stdobject-to-associative-array-by-default-in-un/59911881#59911881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found code in this library. it can change default output StdObject to associative array

```
Unirest\Request::jsonOpts(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parsedBody = json_decode(json_encode($response->body), true);
```

Comment: did you tried to cast it as (array)$response->raw_body